# Device not being recognized for new Xcode projects but is recognized by old projects and Organizer

Tags: xcode

If I create a new Xcode project (just choosing, for example, the Single View Application template) then I cannot get Xcode to recognize the plugged in device.

As you can see from the screenshot my iPhone is called MyName's iPhone and is being recognized by an existing project; as you can see on the right Organizer can recognize it and it too and has displayed the green dot. 
But as you can see in the middle the new created project does not recognize it and is displaying "iOS Device". When I try and execute the new project I get the "Xcode cannot run using the selected device" message.

I've tried exiting/relaunching Xcode, unplugging/replugging the device, tried re-creating new projects, but still the problem persists - *any newly* created project just won't recognize the device but all previously existing project do.

I had the same problem a few weeks ago and the solution then was to just delete the newly created project and create another one. But now I've tried that a few times and its no longer working as a solution.

XCode 5.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device has iOS 7.0.4. What is the new project's Deployment Target? If it's 7.1 then there is your problem. Change the Deployment Target to 7.0 or earlier.